# Do the hits in Lucene rank the documents?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene.net

This is my code:

```
 string word = txtQuery.Text;
 IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open("e:/indexDir");   
 IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);   
 QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Content", new StandardAnalyzer());
 Query query = parser.Parse(word);
 Hits hits = searcher.Search(query);
 int hitCount = hits.Length();
 Response.Write("searcher order--------------</br>");

 for (int temp = 0; temp < hitCount; temp++)
 {
    Response.Write(searcher.Doc(temp).Get("Content") + "</br>");       
 }

 Response.Write("hits order--------------</br>");

 for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
 {
    Document doc = hits.Doc(i);
    Response.Write( doc.Get("Content") + "</br>");
    Response.Write("Score-----" + hits.Score(i)+"Doc id---"+hits.Id(i)+ "</br>");
 }
```

What I found here is that the searcher's document order is simply how it is read by the reader...

But the hits documents order is on the basis of the score of the document...

So is this what we call "RANKING THE DOCUMENTS"???

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here, but essentially Lucene orders results based on the score (i.e. best match compared to weight). The score can be affected by weighting document terms: to set the weight you'll need to look at the payload functionality in Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

**`What I found here is that the searcher's document order is simply how it is read by the reader...But the hits documents order is on the basis of the score of the document`**

No, This has nothing to do with *"ranking the documents"*. `searcher.Doc` is a wrapper for `indexReader.Doc`.  What you do in the first loop is just reading the index(*first N docs in the index*), not the search results.

```
for (int i= 0; i < N ; i++)
{
    Response.WriteLine(searcher.Doc(i).Get("Content"));       
}
```

Your first loop would also work the same, even if you didn't call `searcher.Search`.

If you inspect the outputs of both loops, you will see that they contain different documents actually.

`hits.Doc(n)` *returns nth document in the result list whereas* `searcher.Doc(n)` *returns nth document in the index*

---

Now your question, **`Do the hits in Lucene rank the documents?`**

In Lucene.Net, search results are ordered by `score` by default (if you do not supply sort fields).